# Upload multiple files to firebase firestore in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my Android app, I need to save multiple files into Firebase cloud storage.
The uploads need to complete before I can save the full object to the database (the files are just a part of the full object and I'm saving the upload's download URL for each file in the full object).

If I want to use a WorkManager for this task, how can I make all the files upload first and then upload the full object to its database?
Is there a way to upload all the files as a batch upload instead of putting it all in a loop?
What is the best way to know when all the uploads finished?

Comment: Are you referring to Cloud Storage instead of Firestore?  Firestore is a database and Cloud Storage is for general file uploads.

Comment: You're right, I meant Firebase cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are no batch file upload operations provided by the client SDK.  You will have to use the Task objects returned by each individual upload in order to determine when they are all complete.  You might find it helpful to use [Tasks.whenAll()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) from the [Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) to set up a callback for multiple task completion.

Comment: Do you mean like:
    val tasks = mutableListOf<UploadTask>()
    val uploadTask = ref.putFile(...)
    tasks.add(uploadTask)

and do it in a loop, then, after the loop ends write:
    val finishTask = Tasks.whenAll(tasks)
            finishTask.addOnCompleteListener {
                ...
            }

?

Comment: I'll try, Thanks!